# Azure Service Bus: How to Renew Lock?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

How do I renew the lock on a Receiving Queue Message Handler?
On the Event Handler, test Message does not have renew lock property.

```
Message testMessage;
```

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.renewlock?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RenewLock api link you posted above is from the old deprecated WindowsAzure.ServiceBus nuget package where RenewLock method was part of BrokeredMessage.
[image]

The current package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus (which you are rightly using) has RenewLockAsync method as part of the Receiver https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.messagereceiver.renewlockasync?view=azure-dotnet. You can call that method from your QueueClient instance like  `queueClient.RenewLockAsync(testMessage)` or `queueClient.RenewLockAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken)`.
[image]

But instead of the hard work of doing it by hand, you can leverage the auto-renew lock feature by setting MaxAutoRenewDuration property of MessageHandlerOptions. That would be in method RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues).

```
        static void RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()
        {
            // Configure the MessageHandler Options in terms of exception handling, number of concurrent messages to deliver etc.
            var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
            {
                // Maximum number of Concurrent calls to the callback `ProcessMessagesAsync`, set to 1 for simplicity.
                // Set it according to how many messages the application wants to process in parallel.
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,

                // Indicates whether MessagePump should automatically complete the messages after returning from User Callback.
                // False below indicates the Complete will be handled by the User Callback as in `ProcessMessagesAsync` below.
                AutoComplete = false,

                // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#peeklock
                MaxAutoRenewDuration = <some timespan>
            };

            // Register the function that will process messages
            queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
        }
```

Comment: thanks, I have one last question, our company will get a Microsoft Azure consultant with Microsoft, setting up account  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586898/using-service-bus-queue-with-azure-functions-to-update-sql-table

Comment: what is the point of autorenew? why not just use a longer lockduration without renewing?

Comment: @Wouter , lock duration can be of maximum 5 minutes..so you need renew if you have longer processing time..

Comment: ok... but still it gets autorenewed up until MaxAutoRenewDuration... so just chage this limit of 5 minutes to MaxAutoRenewDuration and you don't need to renew ever. (We have a timeout (artifically limited to 5 minutes)... it's to short we renew... it's hard to renew... we like auto renew.... so we have a longer timeout (limite to MaxAutoRenewDuration?)

Answer (score 4):

Currently, it's recommended to use Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus NuGet package because Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus is out-of-date. Here is a sample code to auto-renew processing messages:

```
var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
var processor = client.CreateProcessor(queueName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions
{
    MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration = TimeSpan.FromHours(100),
});
processor.ProcessMessageAsync += async arg =>
{
    //process your message
    await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);
};
processor.ProcessErrorAsync += async arg =>
{
    //process errors
};
```